# Django 2.2 TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django

I've just started with django. I'm finding so many question about this problem, but I see most of all are outdated. I guess something has changed between 2.1 and 2.2.

This is my tree

```
.
|____posts
| |____migrations
| | |______init__.py
| |____models.py
| |______init__.py
| |____apps.py
| |____admin.py
| |____templates
| | |____posts
| | | |____index.html
| |____tests.py
| |____urls.py
| |____views.py
|____django_project
| |______init__.py
| |____settings.py
| |____urls.py
| |____wsgi.py
|____manage.py
```

This is the content of `posts/views.py`

```
def index(req):
    return render(req, 'posts/index.html')
```

When I try to access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/` I get the error

> TemplateDoesNotExist at /posts/

To me it looks like I've done exactly what https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/ says. What am I missing?

This is the content of settings.py 
https://pastebin.com/qkGhLtsW

Comment: have you included `posts` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: did you add your posts app inside instaled apps in settings.py?

Comment: Have you added `'DIRS': ['templates',],` to the `TEMPLATES` in `settings.py` file ?

Comment: Nothing has changed here since at least version 1.4.

Comment: But please show the TEMPLATES setting.

Comment: I edited with the content of settings.py

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your template is in an application templates directory, but you have not added that application to INSTALLED_APPS, so Django does not know to look there.

Answer (score 0):

Use `'DIRS': ['posts/templates'],` because your templates folder is inside the posts folder...

Answer (score 0):

Within your main settings file you will need to find the list variable

INSTALLED_APPS

Add to the top of the list

```
'posts',
```

Doing this tells your Django system that there is an app that has been created called posts. It will then search within posts for templates and you will begin to see your HTML files